# How Alfresco and SOLR works with indexes queries

Tags: oracle, solr, lucene, alfresco

I have a doubt about how indexed properties works in Alfresco 4.1.6 with SOLR 1.4.

I use something like this for my queries:

```
SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();    
sp.addStore(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
sp.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO);
sp.setQuery(query);
ResultSet results = getSearchService().query(sp);
```

where query variable is something like this:

```
PATH:" /app:company_home/app:user_homes/cm:_x0030_123//*" AND    
((@cm\:title:food) OR (@cm\:name:abcde) OR (TEXT:valles) OR    
(@doc\:custom_property:"report") OR (@doc\:custom_property2:"report") 
AND (@doc\:custom_property3:"report") AND TYPE:"{my.model}voc_document"
```

On my model.xml I specify what custom properties are indexed

```
<index enabled="true">
```

My question is... How works SOLR 1.4 with the indexes if I put on the search query two or more indexed properties? Like Oracle? Oracle try the best index and use only this. Or maybe SOLR combine all the indexed properties and uses all the index on the query?

I need this answer to determine how many indexes put on my model.xml. Maybe put a lot of indexes don't give me the best and efficient result and is better index only a few properties.

And finally, one question. I use LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO, but I can see that exists a LANGUAGE_SOLR_FTS_ALFRESCO. Is the same? I need to use the second if I use SOLR?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

There is only one "index". Every field you mark as indexable (which is enabled by default) ends up in your solr index. Alfresco takes your query and sends it to SOLR for processing.

If you don't have a lot of documents, you can go ahead and index every field. By far the biggest impact on indexing and search is the full text index of the content field, which is enabled by default also.

LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO will use whatever index subsystem you have enabled. In later versions it may use SOLR or the database depending on your configuration. If you try to LANGUAGE_SOLR_FTS_ALFRESCO, it's forcing SOLR, so if you don't have solr enabled, you would have an error.

Regards!